# iPhone image orientation- Rotating images automatically with PHP, PEL, Image_moo

Tags: php, iphone, exif, pel

I'm trying to rotate uploaded images before saving, based on the EXIF ORIENTATION tag.

I've checked each portion of the code separately and everything seems to work on it's own.

$new is the correct path and filename.

Image_moo has been loaded.

PEL(PHP EXIF Library) [http://lsolesen.github.com/pel/] has been loaded.

Images have EXIF data including rotation.

I believe I got the switch statement correct.

The code doesn't cause any errors, it just doesn't rotate the image.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Mark

```
 $new = the file that was just uploaded
 ...
 $ext = strtolower($path_parts['extension']);
 ...

  if($ext == 'jpg'){
  $input_jpg = new PelJpeg($new);
  $exif = $input_jpg->getExif();
  if($exif !== NULL){
  $tiff = $exif->getTiff();
  $ifd0 = $tiff->getIfd();
  if($orient = $ifd0->getEntry(PelTag::ORIENTATION)){
     $this->image_moo->load($new);
     $orient = str_replace(' ', '', $orient);
     if (($tmp = strstr($orient, 'Value:')) !== false) {
          $str = substr($tmp, 6, 1);//Get the value of the ORIENTATION tag
     }
     $this->image_moo->load($new);
     switch ($str)
     {
     case 8:
        $this->image_moo->rotate(270);
        break;
     case 3:
        $this->image_moo->rotate(180);
        break;
     case 6:
        $this->image_moo->rotate(90);
        break;
     case 1:
        break;
     }
     $this->image_moo->save($new, TRUE);
 }
 $output_jpg = new PelJpeg($new);
 $output_jpg->setExif($exif);
 $output_jpg->saveFile($new);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure about `PelJpeg` but in `Imagick` i do:

```
...
switch( $imagick->getImageOrientation() ){
    case 6:
        $imagick->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(), 90);
        $imagick->setImageOrientation(1);
    break;
    case 8:
        $imagick->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(), 270);
        $imagick->setImageOrientation(1);
    break;
}
...
```

Comment: The test page I was using displayed the rotated images just fine but the image gallery was not displaying them correctly.  For some reason it started working after I changed it to set orientation to 1 after rotation `$orient->setValue(1);`.  This step wasn't necessary on the test page.  I must be missing something, but at least it works now.  Thanks for your sample code!

Comment: setImageOrientation basically resets EXIF. If you rotate image 90degree and EXIF says it rotated 90degree in total it's 180